# DexExpress / DevExtreme: Getting msmdpump.dll to work with IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-core, devexpress, ssas, olap, devextreme

I'm upgrading a project from an older version of **DevExpress** to the latest version of **DevExtreme** and having an issue with the pivot grid's **OLAP** connection. In the old version, we could bind to a connection string as follows:

`@Html.DevExpress().PivotGrid(pivotSettings).BindToOLAP("provider=MSOLAP;data source=.;initial catalog=Dashboard AS;cube name=Dashboard Cube").GetHtml()`

In the new one, there is no option for a connection string and I am forced to provide a URL for **msmdpump.dll**.

I followed some of instructions here: [Configure HTTP Access to Analysis Services on IIS 8.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0)

However, that is for IIS and **not** IIS Express, so I basically just copied the files to **/wwwroot/OLAP/** in my new **.NET Core** application.

My pivot grid has the following definition:

`@(Html.DevExtreme().PivotGrid()
    .ID("pivotGrid")
    .Width("100%")
    .AllowSortingBySummary(true)
    .AllowFiltering(true)
    .ShowBorders(true)
    .ShowColumnGrandTotals(true)
    .ShowRowGrandTotals(true)
    .ShowRowTotals(true)
    .ShowColumnTotals(true)
    .FieldChooser(c => c.Enabled(true))
    .DataSource(d => d.RetrieveFields(true)
        .Store(s => s.Xmla()
            .Url("/OLAP/msmdpump.dll")
            .Catalog("Dashboard AS")
            .Cube("Dashboard Cube")
        )
    )
)`

and the **msmdpump.ini** is as follows:

`<ConfigurationSettings>
    <ServerName>localhost</ServerName>
    <SessionTimeout>3600</SessionTimeout>
    <ConnectionPoolSize>100</ConnectionPoolSize>
</ConfigurationSettings>`

The problem is I keep getting a 404 in the browser console even though the URL is correct:
**http://localhost:4116/OLAP/msmdpump.dll**

I can't find any instructions for getting **msmdpump.dll** to work with **IIS Express**.

I'm thinking maybe IIS Express prevents the browser from accessing DLLs directly? I'm not certain... but it did give me a 404 on the **.ini** file as well when I tested that. If this is the problem, how do I solve it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answered at https://github.com/DevExpress/DevExtreme/issues/919

Comment: @amartynov, Yes you did, thank you. However, I still haven't sucecssfully set this up. I keep getting an HTTP 500 error. I will figure it out eventually, but in any case, I think it would be a good idea to support connecting via a connection string an an alternative, so we don't need to care about msmdpump if there's no requirement to set it up that way. It will make things much simpler, especially for development. Are you guys able to do this in a future version? Should I open a separate feature request on one of your GitHub pages (or maybe somewhere else)?

Comment: for MVC/.NET related feature requests, consider https://devexpress.com/sc, GitHub repo is for JavaScript bits. Setting up msmdpump can be challenging, I agree, but it's described in detail in [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/instances/configure-http-access-to-analysis-services-on-iis-8-0)